# Trying to install npm packages and getting EN0ENT errors for everything

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

This is example output from running npm install grunt-cli

Notice the repeating of **node_modules** path?  Is this is an environment path issue?  When I try the same commands on another user on OSX, it works perfectly as expected.

Running latest OSX 10.9.1

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/weak
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bunker
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha/-/mocha-0.3.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/should/-/should-0.3.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tiny-lr/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cli/0.4.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/shanejordan/Documents/Projects/KiddoMath/code/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/resolve/node_modules/tap/node_modules/difflet/node_modules/traverse/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/shanejordan/Documents/Projects/KiddoMath/code
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.24
npm ERR! path /Users/shanejordan/Documents/Projects/KiddoMath/code/node_modules/grunt-cli/node_modules/resolve/node_modules/tap/node_modules/difflet/node_modules/traverse/index.js
```

UPDADE:
I ran **npm cache clean** and received

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/shanejordan/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-jkroso-forEach-f0435201/bra‌​nches' That must be my room problem.
```

Comment: Although I don't know the specific cause of your problem, the repeating `node_modules` is due to dependencies, and the dependencies of the dependencies, and so on.

Comment: Gotcha.  Maybe its not that then.  I can't figure out why that ENOENT keeps happening.  It looks like it starts to work, then it will run like this for 5 minutes...looking like its grabbing every dependency on npm, along with these types of errors.  No matter what package I try and install

Comment: Have you tried looking in the paths that the `ENOENT` errors are thrown on?

Comment: Under which user is the npm installed? Maybe node/npm setup has set up env for the person that installed it, and not for all users?

Comment: I only ever have one user.  I created another one just to test it out to see if it was related to my specific user environment.  Seems like it is.  I did previously install some npm packages with sudo, which I later learned is a no-no.

Comment: Just curious... are you actually running `npm install grunt-cli`? The cli should be installed globally using `npm install -g grunt-cli`. Of course, I don't know how that would cause this issue. The task runner should be installed in the project using `npm install grunt` - and maybe with the `--save-dev` option.

Answer (score 3):

I've hit this in the past and the solution for me that worked was to run

```
npm cache clean
```

and then trying to re-run the npm install command again.

UPDATED:

If it fails with

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink ...
```

then that means the npm process [doesn't have access to remove that directory](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/unlink.html). Did you use `sudo` to run any of the `npm` install commands? If so it might be worth running

```
sudo npm cache clean
```

and then re-running the npm installs without `sudo`

Comment: I ran *npm cache clean* and received npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/Users/shanejordan/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-jkroso-forEach-f0435201/branches'  That must be my room problem.

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache and still it doesn't work, it throws an error " '%E2%80%93g' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it"

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. FWIW, I have had some serious problems installing generators without sudo and found that installing them WITH sudo caused other issues. I uninstalled npm then reinstalled it using nvm (node version manager - nice tool) which virtually ensures that you never have to use sudo again (and many other nice features). I did have to use sudo for npm cache clean but after that everything worked as expected.